.NET MAUI: Video Visibility issue on iOS Platform
I am using webview for playing video in my MAUI appication and it is working fine on Android platform. But in iOS the video is not visible when  starts playing only audio is able to hear.
Below is the code:
<WebView  
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    x:Name="video_webview"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <WebView.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnIdiom.Phone>250</OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>325</OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnIdiom.Desktop>250</OnIdiom.Desktop>
        </OnIdiom>
    </WebView.HeightRequest>
</WebView>

//code behind
video_webview.Source = videoUrl;

Is it a known issue in MAUI? Please suggest a solution for this.
Update:
Below is my complete xaml structure.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="83.9*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
             <!--Header Layout-->
        </Grid>

        <BoxView 
            Grid.Row="1"/>

        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="2">

        </StackLayout>

        <ScrollView
          Grid.Row="3">

            <Grid
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid 
                    Grid.Row="0">
                </Grid>

                <CollectionView 
                    Grid.Row="1">
                    
                </CollectionView>

                <Label
                    Grid.Row="2">
                </Label>
                
                //here is my webview
                <WebView  
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    x:Name="video_webview"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <WebView.HeightRequest>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>250</OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>325</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>250</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </WebView.HeightRequest>
                </WebView>

                <Frame
                    Grid.Row="4">

                <Frame
                    Grid.Row="3">
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

This video visibility issue occurs only on iPhone 14 (iOS 16.4) and earlier versions, while the video displays properly on iPhone 15 (iOS 17.4) and later versions.

Are you wrapping the Webview within VerticalStackLayout or HorizontalStackLayout in root level? If so, can you try to change the root layout to Grid  to see if it works?

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I tried changing the parent stack to grid, but no luck. Audio is hearing but video is not viewable.

Thanks for your response, I can't reproduce your issue, could you please help create Minimal, Reproducible Example and add it to your post?

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I have edited the question with the complete xaml details. Could you please check.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT This video visibility issue occurs only on iPhone 14 (iOS 16.4) and earlier versions, while the video displays properly on iPhone 15 (iOS 17.4) and later versions.

Did you test on simulator or physical device? Better to share the detailed video url. Thanks!

On simulator we are checking. Could you please check with the below video url.
https://player.vimeo.com/video/355002461

Thanks for the update, looks like the link you provided can't be opened on myside, maybe you can provide another available link.
